# Input controls on angular ui grid grouping

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid and the data is grouped by a field called state. Couple of columns  cell template has input control. How do i get rid of the textbox on the row header (row that has expand/collapse icon)? Here is the code that i was playing with

```
columnDefs: [{
        name: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        cellTemplate: '<input type ="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/>'
    },

    {
        name: 'company',
        width: '25%',
        cellTemplate: '<input type ="text" ng-model="row.entity.company"/>'
    },
    {
        name: 'registered',
        width: '40%',
        cellFilter: 'date',
        type: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'state',
        grouping: {
            groupPriority: 0
        },
        sort: {
            priority: 0,
            direction: 'desc'
        },
        width: '35%',
        cellTemplate: '<div><div ng-if="!col.grouping || col.grouping.groupPriority === undefined || col.grouping.groupPriority === null || ( row.groupHeader && col.grouping.groupPriority === row.treeLevel )" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div></div>'
    }
],
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/S6PI3EThd3950WzB5fJv?p=preview